# outside lib in GitHub

Tags: github

I just recently used Github, and when I was trying to upload my java project I realized that I was using some external libraries like apahce poi in this project, and these files have to be stored in libs for my application to function, do I need to upload these files because I realize that might violate some issues(maybe ?).
If yes, then what is the correct way to upload or maybe just post a link to those dependency

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool that provides a dependency management system such as [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) or [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html) (these are both common choices in the Java ecosystem). Your project will then include a configuration file that Maven or Gradle will use to download dependencies so you don't need to distribute them with your project.